# Smarty assign value to variable inside included template

Tags: php, templates, smarty3

I have a listing item template as below:

```
<div class="listing-item">
    <div class="photo">{$thumbnail}</div>
    <div class="title">{$name}</div>
    <div class="price">{$price} {$currency}</div>
    <div class="location">{$city}/{$town}</div>
</div>
```

I'm including this template from another template file, and assign it into a variable named **listing_item**, as shown below:

```
<div class="listing-box-container clearfix">
    {include file="common/product/listing_item.tpl" assign=listing_item}
</div>
```

Now i have var a variable named **listing_item** that holds template for single listing item.

I want to assign value to variable inside **listing_item** like:

```
{assign var="$listing_item.thumbnail" value="Sometown"}
```

I'm not passign values while i'm including the template because i want to use **listing_item** multiple times so i dont want to load it everytime i need it.

The idea here is include the template once, and assign values & echo where it needed.

So, how can i assign value to variable inside a template which has already been included and assigned to a variable?

Or, what is the best practice to archieve my needs in smarty?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If You are using `smarty3` You can use this constuct:

```
{$listing_item = [
    'thumbnail' => 'some_thumbnail',
    'title' => 'some_title',
    'price' => 'some_price'
]}
```

More about variables syntax here http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl

Now pass it to the template:

```
<div class="listing-box-container clearfix">
    {include file="common/product/listing_item.tpl" listing_item=$listing_item}
</div>
```

And within the template use:

```
<div class="listing-item">
    <div class="photo">{$listing_item.thumbnail}</div>
    <div class="title">{$listing_item.name}</div>
    <div class="price">{$listing_item.price} {$listing_item.currency}</div>
    <div class="location">{$listing_item.city}/{$listing_item.town}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i've contacted with the guys on smarty irc and thay told me that when you assign someting to a variable it gets rendered. so you can not assign value to a variable inside a variable. because there is no variable inside variable thats hold template. it's just rendered text now.

and they told me that when you include a template, it loads once anc cached. further includes ignored. so there is no performance penalty. this is what i exactly seeking for. smarty doing it automatically.